# Curious question about Tableau software

Tags: .net, charts, data-visualization, tableau-api

Tableau software presents nice graphs for data visualization. I am curious to know how such nice interactive graphs are generated? Are they support HTML5? What could be nice graphical library for this?

Any help?

Answer (score 11):

Tableau Desktop and Tableau Server share a lot of the same back end code to generate images. Tableau Desktop draws images on the screen and Tableau Server draws into off-screen image buffers and then sends the data as a series JPEG tiles to the browser.

The shared code is custom C++ created by the developers at Tableau Software. For versions 6.1 and earlier, the code used graphics libraries that are part of the MS stack like GDI and GDI+.

Comment: I was looking into Tableau rendering recently having worked with various charting technologies wondering what technology was being used. I was quite surprised to discover that it was server side rendering serving images up that gave the perception of a client side interactive visualization. The speed at which those images are created on mouse over is quite impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you look at the source code of the generated page?

Tableau server is worth several K$. I do not hhink their libraries are freely available - they cost them a lot to develop.